# Diferenças entre os pacotes brglm e logistf

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com uma base de dados em painel que contém informações sobre as empresas de capital aberto da *BOVESPA*. Abaixo segue um pedaço dessa base de dados:

[image: Dados em Painel ~ Empresas BOVESPA]

A minha variável dependente é binária (ROIC.MEDIANA) de forma que comecei a minha estimação via painel logístico. Como os meus dados não são normais, optei por uma estimação LOGIT.

```
setwd("C:/Dados/BOVESPA")
getwd() 
require("openxlsx")
dadosbov <- read.xlsx ("BOVESPA.xlsx") # Importando os dados.
dadosbov <- na.omit(dadosbov) # Omitindo NA's.
dadosbov <- as.data.frame(dadosbov)
attach(dadosbov)
View(dadosbov)
```

Na sequência decidi rodar a função `glm` para estimar os dados:

```
reg1 = glm(ROIC.MEDIANA ~ ECV + MARGEM.EBIT + GIRO.ATIVO + 
ALAVANCAGEM.FINANCEIRA + CICLO.FINANCEIRO + CICLO.OPERACIONAL + HHIE + HHIS 
+ CRISE, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=dadosbov)
```

O que retornou um warning:

> Warning message: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

O modelo é estimado, mas os coeficientes estão errados devido ao problema estatístico de separação em regressão logística. Pesquisando sobre como contornar o problema descobri o trabalho de Firth (1993) que faz o mesmo tipo de estimação corrigindo o problema. No R descobri dois pacotes que realizam a estimação corrigida: `logistf` e `brglm`:

```
require("logistf")
reg2 = logistf(ROIC.MEDIANA ~ ECV + MARGEM.EBIT + GIRO.ATIVO + 
ALAVANCAGEM.FINANCEIRA + CICLO.FINANCEIRO + CICLO.OPERACIONAL + HHIE + HHIS 
+ CRISE, data=dadosbov)
```

Nenhum erro ou *warning* é gerado e consigo ver os resultados do modelo.

```
require("brglm")
reg3 = brglm(ROIC.MEDIANA ~ ECV + MARGEM.EBIT + GIRO.ATIVO + 
ALAVANCAGEM.FINANCEIRA + CICLO.FINANCEIRO + CICLO.OPERACIONAL + HHIE + HHIS 
+ CRISE, family = binomial(logit), data=dadosbov, method = "brglm.fit")
```

Gera um *warning*, mas consigo ver os resultados do modelo:

> Warning message: In fit.proc(x = X, y = Y, weights = weights, start = start, etastart = etastart,: Iteration limit reached

**Minha dúvida é:** qual a diferença entre os dois pacotes? As estimações geradas diferem em relação aos coeficientes gerados. Pelo que pesquisei não consegui encontrar diferenças entre os dois pacotes que justifiquem os outputs produzidos por cada um deles.

Quanto ao *warning* relativo ao brglm, não importa o quanto eu mude os parâmetros da função `brglm.control`, continuo recebendo o mesmo *warning* e os mesmos resultados da estimação.

Comment: Inclua a tag `R` na sua pergunta. `RStudio` é apenas uma interface